# New to bash - "Unexpected end of file"

Tags: bash

I'm trying to set up a simple bash script to check and see if an error message appears in a log, if that error message "reset adapter" appears in that log the server is supposed to email us. Whenever I run the script below I'm met with "Bash Script.sh: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file"

```
 if fgrep 'reset adapter' /var/log/messages.log then 
      mail -s 'Flapping ethernet' alerts@OurAlertBoard.com
 fi
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Added the suggested ; before "then", still getting the same error. New script:

```
 if fgrep -q 'reset adapter' /var/log/messages; then 
      mail -s 'Flapping ethernet' alerts@OurAlertBoard.com
 fi
```

Comment: Add a `;` before `then`.

Comment: Did you add the `-q` option? It's important. `fgrep -q ...`

Comment: whoops, added that.

Comment: Does the script have windows-style line breaks (carriage return followed by linefeed, rather than just linefeed)? If so, that'll prevent bash from recognizing `then<cr>` as a keyword and it'll search the rest of the file looking for `then`, not find it, and give this error.

Answer (score 4):

```
if fgrep -q 'reset adapter' /var/log/messages.log; then 
      mail -s 'Flapping ethernet' alerts@OurAlertBoard.com
 fi
```

- Note the added `;` before `then`
- Also, you need to keep grep quiet and only return an error code. This is done with `-q`
- On most systems, the log files is named `/var/log/messages`. Check if `messages.log` is correct on your system.

Comment: Matt, that should be edited into your question, not posted as a comment.  The loss of formatting makes comments useless for that kind of post.

Comment: I'll put the updated script in the original question